# Getting error when trying to install some python packages in Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, package

I am trying to install some packages from our requirements.txt file. But we are constantly seeing the below error. Any guidance on how to resolve it? Maybe some error in preshed or blis packages? Any dependencies we have to preinstall here? We have Python 3.7.9 installed. It's in 64 Bit.

```
            /tmp/pip-install-aw5ivhl1/blis_f463d355a4f44a76bf2cb429c1a0aa28/blis/_src/include/linux-x86_64/blis.h:1644:13: warning: ‘bli_obj_init_subpart_from’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
             1644 | static void bli_obj_init_subpart_from( obj_t* a, obj_t* b )
                  |             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            error: command '/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1
            [end of output]

        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
        ERROR: Failed building wheel for blis
        Running setup.py clean for blis
      Failed to build preshed thinc blis
      Installing collected packages: wasabi, plac, cymem, wheel, tqdm, srsly, setuptools, preshed, numpy, murmurhash, Cython, blis, thinc
        Running setup.py install for preshed: started
        Running setup.py install for preshed: finished with status 'error'
        error: subprocess-exited-with-error

        × Running setup.py install for preshed did not run successfully.
        │ exit code: 1
        ╰─> [14 lines of output]
            /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py:85: _DeprecatedInstaller: setuptools.installer and fetch_build_eggs are deprecated. Requirements should be satisfied by a PEP 517 installer. If you are using pip, you can try `pip install --use-pep517`.
              dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
            running install
            /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
              warnings.warn(
            running build
            running build_py
            running build_ext
            building 'preshed.maps' extension
            x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.10 -I/usr/include/python3.10 -c preshed/maps.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/preshed/maps.o -O3 -Wno-strict-prototypes -Wno-unused-function
            cc1plus: warning: command-line option ‘-Wno-strict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
            cc1plus: fatal error: preshed/maps.cpp: No such file or directory
            compilation terminated.
            error: command '/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1
            [end of output]

        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      error: legacy-install-failure

      × Encountered error while trying to install package.
      ╰─> preshed

      note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
      hint: See above for output from the failure.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Comment: What is the OS image that you are using on EC2?  Are you deploying new packages in a virtual python environment, or trying to upgrade python in the core OS?